# How to filter out array objects whose 7th character is a colon?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

Edit: Thank you everyone! To make life easier in the future, I think I'm going to try to convert the strings into separate pieces of information as a few people suggested. I am a beginner programmer so it will also be good for me to learn how to do that. Thanks again.

**Main Question:** How do I add a second filter that will select array strings whose 7th character is a colon?

**Explanation:** Okay so this is really specific but I need to set up an array filter that will be able to pull out certain strings if the colon is at a certain point. I'm creating a random episode generator based on arrays where the episodes are logged as "EP: " i.e. "EP102: Cool Episode". Users are also able to pick the season they want to watch from. This is by filtering the episode strings that contain "EP(specifiedSeasonNumber)" and only picking from those. The problem is that when a show has more than 9 seasons, for example when picking from Season 10, the program will pick some from more than just the specified seasons. If choosing from S10, whose episodes are labeled EP1014, for example, the first 9 episodes from S1 can also be chosen as they contain EP10(full: EP105).

My theoretical solution is to add another filter if the season number is >= 10 that makes sure the colon is the 7th character in the string as this won't be true for episode strings in seasons less than 10.

**Existent Filter:**

```
selectFriendsSeasons = epFriends.filter { $0.contains("EP\(seasonNum)")}
```

Please feel free to ask further questions about the situation. Thank you!

Comment: It would be much better if you preprocessed the strings into a structure that has properties for season number, episode number, and title. Then you can much more easily filter and sort and search your arrays of structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use a struct to represent episode rather than play around with strings.

You can check colon position using:

```
$0.index(of: ":") == $0.index($0.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)
```

Comment: This is ultimately what I was looking for, thank you. I'll mark it as the answer. However I think I might look into structs as I haven't even heard of them before, I'm quite beginner level. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to create a proper `struct` that would model your data more easily, then I would suggest that you change the way you encode seasons on 2 digits instead of 1. And that way your filter statement would look like :

```
let seasonNumString = String(seasonNum)
let formattedSeasonNumString: String = seasonNum > 10 ? seasonNumString : "0" + seasonNumString
selectFriendsSeasons = epFriends.filter { $0.contains(formattedSeasonNumString)}
```

Comment: Ohh this took me a bit to understand but that's certainly something to look into as well as I was considering this as an option, too. Thank you.